# Trouble installing Infinit app on Loki

Tags: release-loki

OS: elementary OS 0.4 Loki (64-bit) - Built on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Followed instructions here: https://infinit.io/downloading
Both installing the .deb and manual method did not work.

When navigating to `/opt/infinit/bin/Infinit`, I can see Infinit is listed in the directory. Attempting to open it by running `Infinit` results in the following error:
`/opt/infinit/bin/Infinit: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Tried to reinstall this library but I'm unsure how to do so or if that's the issue.

Comment: From seeing what the error is, I know that by default Elementary OS uses GTK instead of QT. It is possible that not all the dependencies are satisfied. I would check the dependencies against what is installed just to make sure you have all the prerequisite libs installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reported as a bug of missing dependency in Infinit since Ubuntu Trusty. It was answered then as follows:

You can create symbolic links for every libQtxxx.so to libQtxxx.so.4.

Here is a command to do so (You’ll be asked for your password):

> for lib in $(ls /opt/infinit/lib/libQt*.so); do sudo mv $lib $lib.4; done;

Source: http://help.infinit.io/forums/306958-current-bugs/suggestions/8957017-missing-dependency-on-ubuntu-trusty

Comment: So close!
That seemed to clean up the library issue. 
After starting, it ran through the first-run animation GUI but then failed to start afterwards. 


```$ sudo /Infinit/opt/infinit/bin/Infinit
[        infinit.FIST.Fist        ] Fist: impossible to install fonts
[       elle.CrashReporter        ] elle::signal::SyncImpl(0x1f5bec0): impossible set handler for SIGKILL
QxtGlobalShortcut failed to register: "Ctrl+Shift+I" 
QxtGlobalShortcut failed to register: "Ctrl+Shift+O" ```


Running with sudo seems necessary as it clears up a log re-writing incapability from the Infinit app

Comment: There is a problem with Gnome and consecuently with Pantheon as  it is build on top of the GNOME software base. Infinit works with XFCE and KDE too (tested on fresh virtual machine with ArchLinux). Issue affects ArchLinux with Gnome 3 and Ubuntu Gnome as well.

Comment: To keep track of this problem: http://help.infinit.io/forums/285016-infinit-for-other-platforms/suggestions/9770106-support-gnome-shell